# How do I convert the x-genericbytedata-octet-stream to some format which is readable/manageable

Tags: python, image, numpy, opencv

I am calling a imageServer and getting an **x-genericbytedata-octet-stream** in response. So i was wondering if i can convert it into some format which is manageable like ndarray. 
This is what i am getting in response

> ÿ      Ç÷®£®¥Xøan Ð5£ï~KTþ$¹M«_ ü³þœÿ ˆk¡çÆHyAÏbG§ø
>   A«÷g~ŒieÞÁn¦=Ÿüú
>   i.¿†ö@µ2lí~¤ŸðjLóÉ&,X.ó¿:ÿ
>   õ¿*ìüTvèšƒzXÌñÓ\Â•Ÿû[X’iÌƒì€€0wOóÀ®ŸÆm·Ãú‘ÿ
>   §?¡¬ª|f‘Øñx^àÁW\móVà„³Éä˜Óý’3úÔ­pë¬P2€2pGõö?Z’êàÛDÊ=­jÈ¶¤3ÝÝÜb”vägõ¯wÑß
>   z‹8óøŠðy®¤U8³ÄIüÇå^ù§åt]0cìq?à³«Ð¸QñÔkVØ·fàú±ÿ

I want to convert it into an ndarray so that I could use it in opencv.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Pillow and StringIO to convert it to a jpeg image.

> ```
> from PIL import Image
> import StringIO
>
> img = Image.open(StringIO.StringIO(image_data))
> print (img.size)
> ```