# How can I convert byte jpeg data received from live method call to a format which is readable/manageable

Tags: python, arrays, opencv, computer-vision, byte

I have made a successful live method call as per [link](https://doc.developer.milestonesys.com/html/reference/protocols/imageserver_request_response.html):

and using sockets, I am receiving using this code snippet:

```
while True:

  test = s2.recv(4096)

  print(test)
```

---

but the response I am getting is an endless stream of ---> b''

perhaps this link can also shed some light on the matter: [How do I convert the x-genericbytedata-octet-stream to some format which is readable/manageable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52216412/how-do-i-convert-the-x-genericbytedata-octet-stream-to-some-format-which-is-read)

Is there perhaps a way to parse this stream of b''s to get the image stream for processing with openCV ? Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Did you even try the solution of the link you found yourself? If yes, what is the error?

Comment: Hi yes i did and I have been getting back empty byte strings